# .vimrc configuration file does not load when editing with 'sudo'

Tags: vim, vi

I have problem with .vimrc file, the problem is that it sometimes get loaded, and sometimes not.

```
  1 set number
  2 syntax on
  3 set autoindent
  4 map <F2> :!g++ % -Wall -time -O<CR>
  5 echo "it works!"
```

I've added echo to check if it's loaded, and when I type e.g. `vim .vimrc`, it gets loaded and shows me "it works" in terminal, but when I type e.g. `sudo vim test.cpp` it doesn't get loaded, the message doesn't show up. I'm using debian.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you use `sudo`, Vim gets launched under a different user (`root`). As this user has a different *home directory*, another `~/.vimrc` is loaded (or none, if that user doesn't have one). You can solve the problem in multiple ways:

1. You can directly specify the location of your `.vimrc`: `sudo vim -u $HOME/.vimrc` (this won't help with plugins, though).
2. You can use `sudo -e <file>` or `sudoedit`.
3. You can symlink your `.vimrc` (and the `.vim` plugins directory) for root: `sudo ln -s $HOME/.vimrc .vimrc; sudo ln -s $HOME/.vim .vim`
4. You can change the entire home directory of root to be the same as yours (not recommended, because of security and access rights!)

Comment: Please don't symlink user's `.vimrc` to root's one. This way a malicious program can write commands that will be run as root every time your run `sudo vim`.

Comment: @Yassine: Right. Unfortunately, _any_ mechanism for sharing your user's Vim configuration with root has this problem, even when you manually sync the files. You'd have to inspect the _entire_ contents of your `.vimrc` every time; there could indeed a malicious `if $UID == 0 | execute system(...) | endif` (or something even more obfuscated) be hidden in there.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo vim` causes vim to be run as the root user. Which mean vim looks for the the vimrc in root's home directory and not yours.

The two choices you have to fix this are use

```
sudo -e <file>
```

Or copy your vim configuration to root's home directory.

`sudo -e` or `sudoedit` copies the file to a tmp directory and allows you to edit it and then copies it back on save. This is safer than using `sudo vim` and is the recommended way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-E` flag to keep your environment variables, so vim can find your vim config.

> ```
> -E, --preserve-env
> ```
>
> Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables.  The security policy may return an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

Use it like:

```
sudo -E vim /path/to/file
```

But be warned that it is less secure than `sudoedit` as you would be trusting your vim config (and all the plugins) with root access.

Answer (score 0):

I want to use `vim` on an *AWS EC2 Amazon AMI* instance.

Neither of the above answers helped me to get the color scheme or the plugins working with `sudo`. The solution that got it working, however, is to be found [here](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/colors-and-vimrc-in-sudo-and-su-td1168036.html):

In your `.profile`, `.bashrc` or the like add:

```
EDITOR=vim
VISUAL=$EDITOR
export EDITOR VISUAL
```

and then edit the file using `sudoedit /path/to/file`.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sudo vim /etc/sudoers
```

change this line:

```
Defaults env_reset
```

to:

```
Defaults !env_reset
```

and re-login your shell

Comment: This works for my ubuntu 20.04 but don't know why... Anyone who know it can add more explanations.