# .vimrc configuration file does not load when editing as root

Tags: vim

I looked at [.vimrc configuration file does not load when editing with 'sudo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077949/vimrc-configuration-file-does-not-load-when-editing-with-sudo), but the accepted answer doesn't work for me. I have put a test line `echo "it works!"` into my `~/.vimrc`. When I edit a file as user, it works. When I edit a file as root it doesn't. I have linked `.vimrc` and `.vim` to the same in `/root`; so that, they show up there. I have tried `sudoedit`, `sudo vim` and `su` then `vim`, but nothing works.

I have done some more testing and found that `vim -u /home/colin/.vimrc` works while I'm root except that it doesn't find the color scheme. But, `vim -u /root/.vimrc` fails with:

`E282: Cannot read from "/root/.vimrc"`

So, then I tried to `cat .vimrc` and `ls .vim` while root in `/root`, and got

`Too many levels of symbolic links`

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /root/.vimrc` ?

Comment: See my comments above. I didn't try `ls -l`, but it's working now.

Comment: Hi Colin. Please add the solution as an answer, not as an addendum to the question. Please also refrain from adding "SOLVED" into the title; instead, you can mark the question as solved by accepting your answer, once you've posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I got the `Too many levels of symbolic links`, I simply recreated the links. However, when the links were first created, I was in fact able to `cat` and `ls` them as root user from `\root`. So, I don't really know what the problem was or how it was really solved.

Here is what I did though:

1. `su`
2. `vim -u /home/colin/.vimrc` works but can't load plugins
3. `vim -u /root/.vimrc` failed with error message
4. `cd ~` (which took me to `\root` since `su` in step 1 made me root)
5. `cat .vimrc` and `ls .vim` both failed and complained `Too many levels of symbolic links`
6. `rm -r .vimrc .vim`
7. `ln -s /home/colin/.vimrc ./.vimrc`
8. `ln -s /home/colin/.vim ./.vim`
9. `exit`

Answer (score 1):

All I did is just create two simple soft links. Since you will not change the name of the `.vimrc` or `.vim` files, all you need is just add two pointers to your local user's configuration file. Try this in your terminal:

```
sudo ln -s ${HOME}/.vimrc /root/.vimrc;
sudo ln -s ${HOME}/.vim /root/.vim;
```